# How to take the determinant of a partitioned matrix with vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-decomposition, block-matrices

I am attempting to complete the exercises in my textbook on matrix differential calculus. This question is giving me some trouble. These are the problems I am attempting to complete:

> If $|A| \ne 0$, prove that
>
> $$\begin{vmatrix} A & b \\ a' & \alpha\end{vmatrix}=(\alpha - a'A^{-1}b)|A|.$$
>
> If $\alpha \ne 0$, prove that
>
> $$\begin{vmatrix} A & b \\ a' & \alpha\end{vmatrix}=\alpha |A-\left( \frac1\alpha\right)ba'|$$

I found on wikipedia [Determinant of Block Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) which shows how if you have a partitioned matrix you can decompose that matrix into an upper and lower triangular matrix and apply the product rule to the determinant to find it. Seen as follows:

> When $A$ is invertible, one has
> $$\det\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\  C & D \end{pmatrix}=\det(A) \times \det(D-CA^{-1}B)$$
> as can be seen by employing the decomposition
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ C & I_m\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} I_n & A^{-1}B \\ 0 & D-CA^{-1}B\end{pmatrix}$$

My question is how to extend this logic to a partitioned matrix where on wikipedia's example, $B$ and $C$ are vectors. Down the page a bit they state

> When $D$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, $B$ is a column vector and $C$ is a row vector then
>
> $$\det\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\  C & D \end{pmatrix}=\det(D-CA^{-1}B) \det(A)$$

which is essentially what I am trying to prove. I am just not quite sure how to prove this. I have attempted to use laplace expansion, but that didn't really get me anywhere. Not sure if this is because I am missing something, or if laplace expansion is not the proper technique to prove this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please learn [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row and column matrices are special case of general matrices, the same rules apply.

Suppose you have accepted the fact that

$$\det\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end{pmatrix}=\det(A) \det(D-CA^{-1}B)$$

Then by letting $B=b$, $C=a'$ and $D=\alpha$,

We have if $\det(A) \ne 0$,

$$\det\begin{pmatrix} A & b \\ a' & \alpha\end{pmatrix}=\det(A) \det(\alpha-a'A^{-1}b)=(\alpha - a'A^{-1}b) |A|$$

If $\alpha \ne 0$,

\begin{align}\det\begin{pmatrix} A & b \\ a' & \alpha\end{pmatrix}&=\det \left( \begin{pmatrix} 0^T & 1 \\ I_{n-1} & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & a' \\ b & A\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0^T & 1 \\ I_{n-1} & 0\end{pmatrix}^T\right)\\&=\det \left( \begin{pmatrix} 0^T & 1 \\ I_{n-1} & 0\end{pmatrix}\right)^2 \det\left(\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & a' \\ b & A\end{pmatrix} \right)\\&=\det\left(\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & a' \\ b & A\end{pmatrix} \right)\\
&=\alpha \det(A-b\left(\frac1\alpha\right) a')\end{align}

Comment: so $$\det(\alpha-a'A^{-1}b)$$ is the determinant of a constant, is the determinant of a constant just equal to a constant, couldn't find that in the properties of determinants in my textbook.

Comment: nevermind, figured out that the determinant of a 1x1 is just the number.

Comment: yup, you can view it as a diagonal matrix, hence it is equal to the scalar itself.