# Determinant of a block matrix where the diagonal blocks are singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

I have taken reference for this question from [On the determinant of a block matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4370802)

---

Let

$$M:= \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix} $$

where $A$ and $D$ are singular, $\det A = 0$. What is $\det M$? Can one show that $\det M=0$?

Comment: Consider a simple example where the sub-matrices are just $1\times1$: $A = (0), B = (1), C = (1), D = (0) \rightarrow |M| = -1$. So $|M|$ is not necessarily $0$. Whether there is a simple formula to calculate from the sub-matrices, I don't know.

Comment: Yes agree with your answer
Thanks for the cleanup
No I'm not aware of it

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4675492/339790)

Comment: So in the formula using schur component either A or D have to have non zero determinant right? But as @TonyMathew pointed our with A and B having zero determinant we can have non zero determinant for M. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I meant A and D having zero determinant and still M has non zero det

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2913018/339790)

Comment: Thanks! that's what I was looking for